# Open Source library or simple method to detect iPhone 'bumping'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know that there is an iPhone app which lets you bump your phones together (called 'Bump' of course), but is there an open source library that allows you to connect to another phone upon 'bumping' phones...? Is is there an existing iOS API(s) which would allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bump has their own official [API](http://bu.mp/api) but I'm not entirely sure it's open source as you need to register an API key with them before you receive it. Here's a [tutorial iPhone app](http://bu.mp/apitutorial).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be OSS, but that doesn't matter in this case as the real magic is (necessarily) done on their servers. So I guess one could reimplement the API as OSS but without a server that implements the actual matching it's useless. But the Bump site says: *If your app isn't overloading our servers or generating incremental revenue with each bump, chances are the Bump API will be totally free to you.*

Comment: From what I understand the bumping creates a unique signature based on accelerometer readings and further isolates it based on geographic location of the two devices to reduce the chances of misidentifying the devices.